# Jquery not working correctly!

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have the following script --

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

    $("div.settings_frame_tabs_frame").(function () {

        $("div.settings_frame_tabs_heading" ,this).click(function () {

            $("div.settings_frame_tabs_content" ,this).animate({
              height : 'toggle'
            }, 400, 'linear', function() { });

        });

    });

  });
```

And following HTML code --

```
  <div id="settings_frame_email_id_update" class="settings_frame_tabs_frame">
    <div class="settings_frame_tabs_heading">Email ID</div>
    <div class="settings_frame_tabs_content">
          <form action="<?php echo PATH; ?>domail_res/scripts/php/functions/settings_func.php?update=email_id" method="POST">
                 <table width="100%">
                         <tbody>
                                 <tr>
                                      <td align="left" width="35%">
                                           Enter your new <b>Email ID</b>
                                      </td>
                                      <td align="left">
                                           <input type="textbox" class="settings_frame_tabs_textbox" name="settings_email_id" />
                                      </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                      <td></td>
                                      <td align="right">
                                           <input type="submit" class="settings_frame_tabs_submit_btn" value="Update" />
                                      </td>
                                 </tr>
                         </tbody>
                 </table>
          </form>
    </div>
```

Here is the link of the Jsfiddle with CSS.
http://jsfiddle.net/EDxWh/
Anyone have any ideas! Please let me know if you got any ideas with you, please.

Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/ye6tX/ -> With the JS/HTML

Comment: Please describe what you intend to happen with your current code.

Comment: Is there an error message? What exactly is not working?

Comment: Uhm.... you have not told us ***what*** is not working. My idea is to eat something now... not that anyone cares. But I can see that you have a syntax error here `$("div.settings_frame_tabs_frame").(function () {`.

Comment: purple. It would be useful if you'd describe your problem, and your expected results.

Comment: I would recommend setting up a jsfiddle.net page with your code and posting a link here.  And being more specific with what errors you are encountering.

Comment: Right... You want to share with us what is the problem?

Comment: Crap. I will call John Resig on the phone to let him know. This is serious!

Comment: Your fiddle is missing the JavaScript....

Comment: Sorry i forgot to update it. Sorry.
Done. It is now updated!

Comment: View this link http://jsfiddle.net/EDxWh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error.... the console should have told you that:

```
 $("div.settings_frame_tabs_frame").(function () {
 //                          -------^
```

Here you go:

```
$("div.settings_frame_tabs_frame").each(function () {
    $("div.settings_frame_tabs_heading", this).click(function () {
        $(this).next("div.settings_frame_tabs_content").animate({
          height : 'toggle'
        }, 400, 'linear');
    });
});
```

`each` might not be necessary, depending on how many `.settings_frame_tabs_frame` elements exist. You could also do:

```
 $("div.settings_frame_tabs_frame div.settings_frame_tabs_heading")
     .click(function () {...});
```

The other problem was that `div.settings_frame_tabs_content` is not a child of `div.settings_frame_tabs_heading` but a sibling, hence you have to use `$(this).next()`.

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gwUFe/4/)

Comment: yes it told but if you have any suggestions please edit this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/gwUFe/

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing something before .(function() in this line:

```
$("div.settings_frame_tabs_frame").(function () {
```

?

Comment: Yeah I thought so but I want it to be their otherwise I won't be able to include `this` in my code. Have any suggestions what to put their?